# OpenFDA adverse event counts by dates do not add up

Tags: api, openfda

The counts by date range do not seem to add up. For example, the following two queries

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:"ambien"+AND+serious:1+AND+patient.patientsex:1+AND+[2013-01-01+TO+2014-01-01]&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=10
```

and

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:"ambien"+AND+serious:1+AND+patient.patientsex:1+AND+[2012-01-01+TO+2013-01-01]&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=10
```

return 46 and 137 for FATIGUE, respectively. However, a query that combines those two date ranges into one, namely

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:"ambien"+AND+serious:1+AND+patient.patientsex:1+AND+[2012-01-01+TO+2014-01-01]&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=10
```

returns 139 for FATIGUE, instead of 183.

Is this a real issue or a syntax error in the query?

Note that a query avoiding the first day of 2014 (to avoid overlap) does not work at all (I get back "No matches found!")

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:"ambien"+AND+serious:1+AND+patient.patientsex:1+AND+[2013-01-01+TO+2013-12-31]&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=10
```

This seems to be an outright issue with how dates are handled.

Ron

Comment: One issue seems to be that you are not specifying receivedate for your data query. For example, try the following instead of your fourth (and last) URL example: `https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:%22ambien%22+AND+serious:1+AND+patient.patientsex:1+AND+receivedate:[2013-01-01+TO+2013-12-31]&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=10`

Answer (score 4):

Mark is correct - you need to specify the date field that you want to search on. `receivedate` tends to work best.

Comment: It appears receivedate only accepts a single date, as in

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:%22ambien%22+AND+serious:1+AND+patient.patientsex:1+AND+receivedate:2005-11-30&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=10

When I submit Mark's suggestion I get

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": ""
  }
}

Comment: It looks like Mark's suggestion doesn't work if you copy and paste due to encoding errors. Additionally, you need to wrap your date ranges in brackets. I used https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:%22ambien%22+AND+serious:1+AND+patient.patientsex:1+AND+receivedate:[2013-01-01+TO+2013-12-31]&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=10 and got results as expected.

Comment: It was a cut and paste issue. The hyphens were non-ascii ([2013-01-01+TO+20%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B13-12-31]). This solved the issue and the results I am getting are now accurate. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, on second thought, those are the UTF-8 sequences for "ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER" (E2 80 8C) and "ZERO WIDTH SPACE" (E2 80 8B). They are invisible in the URL string but the service does not tolerate them.